# How to Generate Random Variables then Use in Calculations in pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, random-numbers

I'm basically trying to create multiple versions of a worksheet, each with different values for the variables in each question.  To do this I'm defining random variables, then each time I compile the values change and I print a "new" version of the worksheet.

I understand how to create the random variables by using `\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfrandomseed}` and defining my variables in my desired ranges as e.g. `\def\A{pgfrandom{1,10}\pgfmathresult}`

The problem I run into is that I want to generate an answer for each problem at the end of the worksheet.  But it wants to do the calculation for the answer with a different random value than the one generated in the original question.

e.g. If I say

```
\def\A{pgfrandom{1,10}\pgfmathresult}

\def\B{pgfrandom{10,20}\pgfmathresult}

\def\answer{\A + \B, \pgfmathresult}
```

and I ask the question:

```
What is \A + \B?

\answer
```

It will produce something like....

```
What is 2 + 12?

5 + 19, 24
```

So how do I get it to display the answer a) without showing the calculation itself (i.e. 2 + 12) and b) how do I get it to not re-generate a new random variable when computing the answer?

Sorry, I hope my questions are clear.  I'm new to all this.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 18):

Based on your question you could do this:

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % provide seed for pseudo random generator
% (change to constant, to get the same random numbers on every time compiling)

% new command to init variables
\newcommand\initVariables{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(1,10)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(10,20)}%
}

\newcommand\answer{\pgfmathprint{int(\A + \B)}} % define command to calculate result


\begin{document}
\initVariables % initialize variables (do this every time you need new numbers)
What is $\A + \B$?

Result is \answer
\end{document}
```

### Result

> What is 2 + 12? 
> Result is 14

### Fun with layers ;)

You could use layers to hide the answer, until the solution layer is enabled (you didn't ask for it, so this is just for fun).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{ocg-p}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} % provide seed for pseudo random generator 

% new command to init variables
\newcommand\initVariables{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(1,10)}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(10,20)}%
}

\newcommand\answer{\pgfmathprint{int(\A + \B)}} %define command to calculate result
\begin{document}
\initVariables%initialize variables (do this every time you need new numbers)
What is $\A + \B$?

Result is 
\begin{ocg}{result layer}{1}{0}
\answer
\end{ocg}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: I actually do this a lot (http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm) but use C programs to generate the questions and LaTeX to typeset them.  I create two separate files, one for the questions and one for the answers.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I didn't really try it, but it sounds that you want to use LuaTeX, right?

Comment: Don't even know whtat LuaTeX is.  No, I use Dev_C++.  Anyway, you might consider putting the answers into floats which won't be printed until the last page.

Comment: exuse me, but is your discussion related to this answer or the question? (I just got a little bit confused)

Comment: I should have put these comment on the original question.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Which PDF viewer software are you using to show/hide the layers?

Comment: @MathiasMagdowski This is the Adobe Reader

Answer (score 5):

A `sagetex` solution using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/). Set up variables in `sagesilent` mode. Access the variables in your document through `\sage` command while you typeset.

```
\documentclass[12point]{article}%
\usepackage{sagetex}%  use Sage for it's math ability
\pagestyle{empty} % remove the page numbers
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
var('x')
a = Integer(randint(1,9))
b = Integer(randint(1,9))
\end{sagesilent}
% *********** END DEFINE VARIABLES ****************
\noindent What's $\sage{a}+\sage{b}$? $\sage{a}\times\sage{b}$?    $\sage{a}\div\sage{b}$?\\
Answer: $\sage{a}+\sage{b}=\sage{a+b}$, $\sage{a}\times\sage{b}=\sage{a*b}$ and $\sage{a}\div\sage{b}=\sage{a/b}$\\
You can get a decimal for the division $\sage{a}\div\sage{b}\approx\sage{(a/b).n(digits=5)}$
\end{document}
```

Here's the output running in [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects):
[image]