# Problem generating a random worksheet

Tags: random-numbers

I've been trying to adapt the steps given here.
[how-to-generate-random-variables-then-use-in-calculations-in-pdflatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151375/how-to-generate-random-variables-then-use-in-calculations-in-pdflatex)

My MWE is below (and I apologise for the code being a bit clunky!)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{pgf}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} 
\newcommand\initVariables{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\E}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\F}{random(-10,10)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{random(1,10)}%
}

\newcommand\ansa{\pgfmathprint{int(\A + \R)}}
\newcommand\ansb{\pgfmathprint{int(\B + \R)}}
\newcommand\ansc{\pgfmathprint{int(\C + \R)}}
\newcommand\ansd{\pgfmathprint{int(\D + \R)}}
\newcommand\anse{\pgfmathprint{int(\E + \R)}}
\newcommand\ansf{\pgfmathprint{int(\F + \R)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\initVariables% initialize variables (do this every time you need new numbers)
$y=x+\R$\\[0.3cm]
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{|c}|}
        \hline
    $x$&$\A$&$\B$&   $\C$      &   $\D$      &       $\E$                &       $\F$\\
        \hline
    $y$   &   $\ansa$   &   $\ansb$   &   $\ansc$   &   $\ansd$ &$\anse$   &  $\ansf$\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The code compiles, but I have a string of zeros before the equation
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the zeros?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems the issue is the negative sign; Try using `\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{random(1,21)-11}` instead.

Comment: It looks there is a bug in that function as mentioned by @cslstr, try `\pgfmathparse{int(rand*10)}\let\A=\pgfmathresult`. It works well for me.

Comment: @bbujeya, did the other comments fix your problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you!  I posted this one a couple of years ago!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved in the comments